# Concatenate in a "for loop"

Tags: python, concatenation

I have 2 netCDF files (called 1.nc and 2.nc) in a directory (say dir).
Since they are both identical, I have a function to read the variable that I want from each:

```
varA = myfunction(1.nc)
varB = myfunction(2.nc)
```

where I type:

```
varA.shape 
varB.shape
```

and I get dimensions (for both varA and varB):

```
(31,180,360)
```

Now, I concatenate them with:

```
BB = np.concatenate((varA,varB))
```

and I get dimensions:

```
BB.shape
(62,180,360)
```

which is what I want.

But, if I try to do the same job automated (in case that I have 50 similar files) in a for loop I write:

```
for fname in sorted(glob.glob(dir +'*.nc')):
    print fname
    BB = np.concatenate((myfunction(fname)),axis=0)
```

The print statement gives 1.nc and 2.nc (as expected) and

myfunction(fname) is the read of the variable that I want, with dimensions (31,180,360) like before.
What I get after the loop is BB with dimensions:

```
BB.shape
[5580, 360]
```

Any idea why?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're only calling concatenate on one input `myfunction(fname)`, what are you trying to concatenate that with? You also ovewrite BB each time in the loop, are you trying to concatenate BB with each `myfunction(fname)` object in the list?

Comment: Thanks for your time Karl. How can I concatenate both (or any number of) files in this loop?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are not concatenating anything together with your `np.concatenate` call. You are only overwriting what is stored in `BB` each time in the loop with each `fname` in your collection.

What you need to do is pass in `BB` to your concatenation so that you keep adding to it.

```
BB = np.empty([0, 180, 360])  # Init BB as empty array with correct shape

for fname in sorted(glob.glob(dir +'*.nc')):
    print fname
    BB = np.concatenate((BB, myfunction(fname)), axis=0)  # Concat together BB and myfunction call
```

I am not too familiar on numpy, so the creating an empty array part might not be in the correct format to match the shape of your data. So modify that as needed to match the format.

Comment: I get an error message: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions..

Comment: I think I did it as Karl suggested, but I define an empty array in the beginning with the same dimensions as the ones to be concatenated with BB = np.empty([0, 180, 360]), instead of BB = np.array([]).

Comment: @NickEvangeliou yes sorry, it probably is due to me not knowing the correct way to shape the array initially to match your data's dimensions. I will update my answer.